# Find the package that installed /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk

Tags: debian, dpkg

I have two identical directories in `/usr/lib/jvm` on my **Debian** machine.

- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386`
- `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386`

And I want to get rid of what is not needed.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/bin/javac
openjdk-8-jdk-headless:i386

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386/bin/javac
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386/bin/javac

$ dpkg -l | grep openjdk
openjdk-8-jdk
openjdk-8-jdk-headless
openjdk-8-jre
openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm
```

you’ll see that `java-1.8.0-openjdk-i386` is a symlink to `java-8-openjdk-i386`, so there’s nothing to get rid of.

In such cases `dpkg -S` only finds the symlinks, it doesn’t dereference them:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/jvm/java-*-openjdk-i386
```

should indicate that both “directories” come from `openjdk-8-jdk-headless`.